# Showing JUnit view in Eclipse when running tests from Code

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

When I run just my Testclass in Eclipse I get the JUnit view showing the tree structure and if the test was successful. If I start my Test from code:

```
JUnitCore core = new JUnitCore();
core.run(SimpleTests.class);
```

the view does not show. Can I change this?

Comment: I assume you're talking about eclipse's junit view?

Comment: Yes we are using eclipse. Any ideas?

Comment: Dont think you can with JUnitCore. Why would you even start the tests like this?

Comment: Ok thanks can´t find a solution either. Because of a dynamic structure I am using it would be nice.

Answer (score 12):

On your toolbar click Windows-->Show View-->Others. 
 Type "Junit" without quotes. Select from list and click OK.

Comment: The problem is the View will not show anything even if I open it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you run your code in the main method like this example :

```
public class MiniTest extends TestCase
{
@Test
public void test()
{
    System.out.println("Running test");
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JUnitCore core = new JUnitCore();
    core.run(MiniTest.class);
}
```

In this case, **it will not show your view** because you launch your program as a java application (alt-shift-X-J). You will see "Running test" in the console but that is.
If you want to see the Junit View **you must launch your program as a Junit test** (alt-shit-X-T).
Note that with this manner the main() is not necessary, Eclipse will directly launch the method tagged with @Test. You can also group tests with @Suite.

Answer (score 0):

You can't interact with the JUnit view from your code using JUnitCore.

You can however, add your tests to the JUnitView if you use a [@Parameterized](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.java) test, or if you implement your own test runner. Try extending the [Suite](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runners/Suite.java) class and reimplement one of the constructors with the tests that you want to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem from time to time.

There is something corrupted in the eclipse workspace.

The only solution for me is to create a new workspace and bring in the projects.

It's a serious pain when there are fifty projects in the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

If the view doesn't show, go to Window -> Perspective -> Reset Perspective..