# Eclipse Unit Testing window is missing

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, unit-testing, junit

I got a question about Eclipse ( Im on 4.7.3 afaik ) . I want to know where I could get this C++/C Unit testing Window ?

[image: JUnit window]

It's missing in my Eclipse and the Test is just running in the console like this https://coderwall-assets-0.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/picture/file/648/Schermata_2012-10-06_alle_00.25.40.png

Comment: what are the options you can see, when you right click on project -> Run As

Comment: On the “Windows” menu should be “Show View”, submenu, with a short list of common views, followed by “Other Views...”.  Selecting “Other Views...” will open a dialog with all the possible views you can open, grouped by category.  If you cannot find the view there, you may be missing the correct plugin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing JUnit view in Eclipse when running tests from Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230876/showing-junit-view-in-eclipse-when-running-tests-from-code)

Comment: I dont have anything in Show View with Junit and when i click on project -> Run as my options are running with Local C/C++ Application.

Does someone know which plugin i may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I solved it, it was a package missing. it was a c++ package named "C/C++ Unit Testing Support" . After installing that through the Help -> Install New Software it came in the Show View submenu in Windows and I could add it.

Thanks for your help guys.